# Call function(view) as though onClick

Tags: java, android, pebble-watch

I have a function `void buttonPress(View v)` that is called `android:onClick="buttonPress"`.

I am now implementing an interface to a Pebble app, and I want to call `buttonPress()` from my `receiveData` handler.

What do I pass for `View`? If I remove the requirement, it force closes when called via button or Pebble. If I pass it `null` from the Pebble handler, it behaves on click, but force closes when Pebble triggers.

I do not *need* the button, that was purely to test the Android app. But I do need to call this function which does reads a file and then triggers an intent, and I'm not sure what I need to pass as the `View`, because it's not clear to me what is passed as this parameter if triggered `onClick`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function `void buttonPress(View v)` the view that generates the event is passed as parameter. Since multiple views can be mapped to the same function, `View v` allows you to identify the button that generated the event.

You can pass NULL to that function if you want, and it is completely harmless. After all it is just a function like any other in your class.

Your code must be doing something wrong elsewhere.

Comment: If I pass `null`, it only crashes if triggered by Pebble though.

Comment: I know, but that is not the problem. I use the same technique in my projects. Maybe if you post some code (your onClick) I might take a look at it.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry - you were quite right. Signedness of an integer to blame. Should I delete the Q? Though it helped me I'm not sure how this or future answers can benefit anyone else.

Comment: Good! I would leave the question. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this :

```
void buttonPress(View v)
{
  doWork();
}
```

`and from your receive handler you can call doWork()`.

so it remain same as what button press do and what your receive handler do.
put your read file code and whatever else you want to do in **doWork** method.